# Create a Structure page with entries list

Tags: entries, structure

I have created a Structure page 'Products' with a URL of '/products' so that I can write a description etc, but then I would also like to pull in the Products into the template. I'm a little unsure on how best to achieve this.

The Sections are created as follows;

Page
Handle: page
Type: Structure
URL Format: {slug}
Entry Template: page/_entry

Product
Handle: product
Type: Channel
URL Format: products/{slug}
Entry Template: products/_product

In ExpressionEngine I would have pulled in a Channel entries tag for the page and then another entries tag for the products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to deal with this, but it really depends on how you have the rest of your sections set up. If the structure is exclusively products with only a single root level item called "products" then I would probably suggest storing content for the products overview page somewhere else. This will greatly simplify your products structure (you could even change it to a 'channel' if there is no other reason for the hierarchy). Where you decide to store the product index/overview info is up to you. You could, for example:

- create a single called "products" (with uri '/products'), or
- add it to the "pages" structure as "products" (with a custom Entry Type "products"), or
- create a template "products/_index.html" with description fields, etc. stored in a global set called "productsDescription" (or whatever you like).

Whichever way you choose the product index page will still be "/products/" and the product detail pages will still be "/products/product-slug/".

If you do decide to place the products overview in the "pages" section, for example, you can just check for the entry type using a conditional or `switch` statement (within the 'page/_entry.html' template), like so:

```
{% if entry.type == "products" %}
    {# display products index page template here #}
{% endif %}
```

However you decide to do it, you can load the actual products like so (as Marion suggested above):

```
{% for product in craft.entries.section('product') %}
    {{ product.title }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: As per his description, he already has the products in a channel section "product" and wants the index to be an entry of his "page" structure section. But that's what you suggested in the lower part of your answer anyways :)

Comment: Thanks Douglas. Just wanted to make sure that using a single template for all of my pages didn't have overhead  with a conditional to display products for those pages that wouldn't show the products.

Comment: @doubleplusgood don't worry about performance with Twig code like conditionals and includes. Did you read this Doc article: ["How can I give each Entry Type its own template"](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/entry-type-templates)?

Comment: @doubleplusgood I agree with carlcs. The overhead is insignificant. I would design the system in whatever makes most sense from a organizational, development and user perspective.

Answer (score 1):

If your channel is `products`, you list them like this on their index page (which is presumably your '/products' page)

```
{% for p in craft.entries.section('products') %}
  {# p is our product. display it however #}
  {{p.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Marion. I guess what I would also like is to pull in the structure page content for 'Products' into the same template but my Page section/channel uses the page/_entry.html template rather than products/index.html